# Need explanation on how Yii::app()->name works

Tags: php, oop, yii

Hello guys I was confused to what Yii::app()->name meant. I know that Yii::app() is calling the static function app() in the YiiBase class, but there is no property name in that same class, can someone explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CApplication there is a public property named 'name'

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication

> name property public string $name; the application name. Defaults to
>   'My Application'.

this mean that

```
 Yii::app()->name
```

simply refer to the name public attribute

in index.php  you have

Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

In Yii  YiibBase class  the

```
createWebApplication()  
{return}    CWebApplication
```

and CWebApplication  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication

extend CApplication ..

> Inheritance    class CWebApplication » CApplication » CModule »
>   CComponent

Comment: I found that too, but I was wondering how does it get to CApplication. I only see it  'return self::$_app '?

Comment: What is the connection between the public name property in CApplication and the app() static function in YiiBase?

Comment: I have update the  answer with(hope)  the explanation you are looking for

Comment: What is the need to 'return self::$_app '? Is there something in the static property $_app, or is it based of off just inheritance.

Comment: I'm not sure  (now mainly i work with yii2) but if i remember right $_app is just for inheritance and internal reference ..

Comment: Does yii2 get rid of the singleton pattern, or do they still use it. Also, how much is yii2 easier to understand?

Comment: The use of the singleton is essential not only for Yii (Yii1 or Yii2) but for all the frameworks I know in different languages .. I've always found it convenient to use the Singleton at the application level and where it was not available I created .. ..Yii2 said this is very clear, orderly ... powerful and intuitive then Yii1 ..I was already comfortable with Yii1 and Yii2 I am fine .. having the PHP 5.4 functionality has completed the framework below engineering profile ... I can write the code very effectively .. and the code is always executed very quickly ..

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies, I really appreciate it. I would also like to ask if you have any recommended resources to master yii1, am going to focus on yii2 soon.

Comment: master yii1 or Yii2 .. ?

Comment: All i have learned about Yii1 came for Yiiframework site and google .. (stakoverflow include)  in the past year was more easy find good info about yii1  on the web .. the advent of yii2 gradually make this a bit more difficult ..  if you have not already done .. take a look http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/ and to the wiki

Comment: Perhaps you do not know but you can also mark an answer  as an answer useful .. you can use the up arrow next to the answer .. the arrow upwards by a positive vote (+10 points), the down arrow a negative vote (-2punti)

Comment: one question, I was reading a book an apparently they said that the name property refers to the config file in main.php, as opposed to another class. What do you think about that?

Comment: The attribute is the same  .. usually the name is setted in config/main.php   but is simply a shortcut for initializing  the name